# URLDownloadToFile cache? unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, caching, download

I am making a simple text chat console application that downloads a file from my FTP. adds the message and re-uploads it. The user can press 'r' at any time to refresh chat. (chat.txt file gets deleted and redownloaded)

Unfortunately URLDownloadToFile is downloading chat.txt from its cache and not displaying the updated chat file.

I need to clear the cache before re-downloading.

I've been googling and found I can use DeleteURLCachEntry. However for me this is not working. See screenshot.

[image: VB Error]

I have Wininet.h included

[image: INCLUDED]

Cant seem to find what I am doing wrong, possibly a simple mistake...

How do you add Wininet .lib and .dll

Comment: Did you add the appropriate library for linking?

Comment: I think I am missing Wininet lib and dll.. how do I go about adding them?